# Python Graph time over timedelta

Tags: python, graph, timedelta

I'm trying to graph a large number of integer/timedelta points over the last few years, I can't seem to find anything that makes much sense. I'm using Python and the format is a tuple (int, timedelta). Anyone know how to do this? I have no experience with any python graphing tool. I've seen a couple things that change the timedelta to a number and just have a day past the start date, but is there any way I can have of intervals of one day on the graph and keep the X-Axis as a day/month/year sort of arrangement

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are trying to do?  I'm not sure what you are looking for here.

Comment: I'm wanting to graph the (int/timedelta) tuples over the last few years in intervals of days. Each point is an int and timedelta